# PyTorch: element-wise max over all data points with the same output bin index

Tags: pytorch, histogram, bin

I am using PyTorch (1.8). Is there a clever way to take an element-wise max over all data points with the same output index?

Let's say I have a data tensor of size (N, M), and an index tensor of size (N,) containing indices [0, K).
Now I want to bin the data tensor into a tensor of size (K, M) according to the index values, but if two or more datapoints are binned into the same slot, then I want to keep an element-wise max.

I've seen a naive approach like the one below, but doesn't give the element-wise max but just stores whatever is binned last.

```
data = torch.randn((N, M))
index = torch.randint(K, (N,))
output = torch.zeros((K, M))

output[index] = data
```

At the moment I am implementing a custom cuda kernel to solve this issue, but would like to know if this can be solved with standard PyTorch.

Edit: Minimal example:

```
data = torch.tensor([[10,1],[9,2],[8,3],[7,4],[6,5]])
index = torch.tensor([2,1,0,1,2], dtype=torch.long)
# something happens
# expected output: 
# [[8, 3], [9, 4], [10, 5]]
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: @Ivan Sure, edited question just now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyTorch doesn't seem to have a native implementation for this yet, but there is a repository which does exactly this.
[PyTorch Scatter](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter)

What I was describing seems to correspond with scatter_max.

```
from torch_scatter import scatter_max

scatter_max(data, index, dim=0)
```